# IIS Express prevent reloading when code changes

Tags: c#, typescript, msbuild, config, iis-express

I've got a pair of IIS Express applications. One of these is extremely heavyweight (20+ second start time on development machines). One of these is extremely lightweight and just serves up scripts.

The problem is that when you build the lightweight application (to rebuild the scripts), IIS Express restarts *both* of them even though only one changed. I've confirmed that the C# side is actually not rebuilt as the C# did not change; so presumably it's actually a VS feature to do this?

Currently we use an external tool to build the scripts (Gulp) to work around this so you can build from the command line, but we need some MSBuild features so we wish to move back to exclusively MSBuild.

We discussed removing our dependency on IIS Express for the lightweight application that would mitigate the problem, but it turns out this is extremely complicated for us due to how the two interact.

Is there a config flag somewhere we can set which will tell IIS Express not to restart if the code for one application changes?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out this was fixed in VS2017 - our C# side no longer builds, so IIS Express does not rebuild and everything is fine.